# Seeing log messages only in certain classes

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Hello I'm seeing log messages only in certain classes and don't know where to look. Did I make mistake with my log pattern or ? This is my log4j configuration, I'm using it with sfl4j :

```
<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%t] (%13F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Application Loggers -->
<logger name="com.stackoverflow.test">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
<logger name="org.springframework.core">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.beans">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.context">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

I'm creating logger like this, class field :

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashboardController.class);
```

and logging like :

```
logger.info("this variable x has value -> {}", x);
```

any thoughts ?

**Update**

Changed to info according to Petar Minchev answer but still I get nothing gets logged.

**Update II**

Now after adding some dependencies this works on some classes (still not on some other). There are some classes that implement runnable and they're run in multiple threads and I don't get log messages from those

Comment: I use tomcat sorry for omitting that detail

Comment: To which package belongs your `DashboardController.class`?

Comment: it belongs to (following the mock package name I set) `com.stackoverflow.test.controllers`

Comment: In this case it should work. Check for typos in your (real) logger name.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use log4j instead? Do you have the correct declarations in the pom.xml file?

Comment: It is OK to use slf4j but if you use it with log4j you also have to declare the dependency `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12`. If not you will get an error like this `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".` - Check [this](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder).

Answer (score 3):

Change `<priority value="warn" />` to `<priority value="info" />`.

`logger.info` does not show when you use `warn` priority.